# Javascript to login to a site for windows store app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a windows store app using HTML and javascript. I need to login into a site with username and password from my application.

Example: http://www.160by2.com/index

The application reads the username and password and sends it to the website. After verification, the website response is shown in the application as "Login success!" or "login failure"...

I'm a novice in windows app development :)

I would be very thankful if sample code is posted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if that is your own website you can publish an RESTful API that can be accessed from your application with XHR. If not you have to see what the POST/GET message sent to the server when you are login to the website. You can intercept the message by using Developer Tools in Chrome or Fiddler to analyze the HTTP message

Comment: this is not my website. Can you explain me in detail? :)