# Logging users into my website via Windows 8 Store app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a website with authentication system written with the Web Pages framework (Webmatrix) and is hosted on a Windows Shared hosting server.

Now I am creating a new app, and it will be a sort of catalog that allows you to browse products that are listed on the site (and some that aren't).

In order to place an order via the Windows 8 app, they will be required to login. I want to log them in using the already-existing code that is based on the website. How can I do this? Are there any Docs, articles/tutorials or sample code that demonstrate this? I've yet to find any.

Comment: Don't forget some people might like to use 'alt + leftarrow' for back (and 'alt + rightarrow' for forward)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that could answer your question but a similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508516/javascript-to-login-to-a-site-for-windows-store-app)

You can find more information about connecting a website and a windows store app [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh781489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761504.aspx) is a link to help connecting a Windows Store app with a web service.

I really hope this may help you for your development

Comment: Thank you Nicolas, the answer in that question did help.